# Exponential and Logarithmic Expressions

Tags: logarithms, contest-math, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

Solve in $\mathbb{R}$ the following equation:
$
(3^x+2)^{\log_5(3)} + 2 = (5^x-2)^{\log_3(5)}
$

My approach:
$
(3^x+2)^{\log_5(3)} + 2 = (5^x-2)^{\log_3(5)} = t
$

After some simplification, we get:
$
5^x = 3^{\log_5(t)} + 2 \quad \text{and} \quad 3^x = 5^{\log_3(t-2)} - 2
$

Adding these two, we get:
$
3^x + 5^x = 3^{\log_5(t)} + 5^{\log_3(t-2)}
$

I tried considering a function, but we have $t$ and $t-2$ which are different. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $x = 1$ works for sure.

Comment: @Abezhiko Do any other solutions rather than 1 work?

Comment: There are not another solution. Because of the graphs of the function logarithm is convexe it can be just one solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have an expression of the form $A^{\log_5(3)}+2=B^{\log_3(5)}$ which implies that the fractional parts of exponentials are equal, i.e.$\{A^{\log_5(3)}\}=\{B^{\log_3(5)}\}$.This is rare enough excepting when both are zero.

Remember that $\boxed{a^{\log_a(b)}=b}$ we look at the equations $5^x-2=3$ and $3^x+2=5$ and apply the boxed formula so we get $3+2=5$.

The solution is $x=1$

Comment: I don’t understand the part with the fractional parts

Comment: @math.enthusiast9: For all real number $x$, you have $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$ so if $x+n=y$, with $n$ integer, the fractional part of $y$ should be equal to $\{x\}$.